# MySQL having count (*) > 1

Tags: mysql, having

```
SELECT  timestamp, symbol from nse.cmBlkstg
Group by timestamp, symbol
having count ( * ) > 1;
```

Doesn't return any rows. Getting

> Error Code: 1046. No database selected

Select the default DB to be used by double-clicking its name 
in the SCHEMAS list in the sidebar. 0.00036 sec. Please help

Comment: **No database selected** read it

Comment: `Error Code: 1046. No database selected` This means that you didn't select a database. you can use `SELECT * FROM database.table` or select a database

Comment: Which tool? Error is just clear, so you are not selecting correctly

Comment: Am using MYSQLbench tool

Comment: SELECT  timestamp, symbol from nse.cmBlkstg
Group by timestamp, symbol; << working fine>> after adding having condition, am getting Error Code: 1046. No database selected Select the default DB to be used by double-clicking its name 
in the SCHEMAS list. Please throw some lights

Comment: `timestamp` is a reserved word; it could be causing weird issues. Try enclosing it in `\``

Comment: I have changed data type. Query is select count ( * ) from nse.bulk_deal; Still am getting. 19:38:33 select count ( * ) from nse.`bulk_deal` Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '*)

Answer (score 0):

Its works well after executing

```
  SET @@SQL_MODE = CONCAT(@@SQL_MODE, ',IGNORE_SPACE');
  SET @@GLOBAL.SQL_MODE = CONCAT(@@GLOBAL.SQL_MODE, ',IGNORE_SPACE');
```